# Length of parameter causes method to throw 404

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've got an AngularJS application running on ASP.NET MVC with WebAPI.

I have a rich text box and when a button is clicked, I want to create a request to the WebAPI to save the new information. I already have such a method in place and it works fine when the rich text data length is around 1643 characters long. However, if I increase the size of the text to 2132 characters, I get a 404 error when I attempt to send the request. I assume it's because the length of this text is too long.

What can/should I be doing differently to resolve this issue so that I can have larger amounts of text in my text box?

Here's the angular service code I'm using:

```
updateData: function(text) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var params = { text = text };
  $http({method: 'POST', url: '/myURL', params: params})
  .success(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status) {
    deferred.resolve(status);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: you should send it as post data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PSL said, you should be sending it as the payload instead of url parameters

```
updateData: function(text) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var params = { text = text };
  $http({method: 'POST', url: '/myURL', data: params})
  .success(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status) {
    deferred.resolve(status);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```